# Ошибка No ModelAndView found

Tags: java, hibernate, crud

Здравствуйте, только начала изучать spring, maven, hibernate. Пытаюсь написать простое crud приложение. Запускаю, выскакивает ошибка java.lang.AssertionError: No ModelAndView found. Не могли бы подсказать, в чём может быть проблема? Тестовый класс :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration("file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/mvc-dispatcher-servlet.xml")
public class AppTests {
private MockMvc mockMvc;
@SuppressWarnings("SpringJavaAutowiringInspection")
@Autowired
protected WebApplicationContext wac;

@Before
public void setup() {
    this.mockMvc = webAppContextSetup(this.wac).build();
}

@Test
public void simple() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/"))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(view().name("hello"));
}
}
```

Контроллер :

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
private UserService userService;

@Autowired(required = true)
@Qualifier(value = "userService")
public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
    this.userService = userService;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String listUsers(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("user", new User());
    model.addAttribute("listUsers", this.userService.getListUsers());

    return "users";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/users/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addUser(@ModelAttribute("user") User user){
    if(user.getId() == 0){
        this.userService.addUser(user);
    }else {
        this.userService.updateUser(user);
    }

    return "redirect:/users";
}

@RequestMapping("/remove/{id}")
public String removeUser(@PathVariable("id") int id){
    this.userService.removeUser(id);

    return "redirect:/users";
}

@RequestMapping("edit/{id}")
public String editUser(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("user", this.userService.getUserById(id));
    model.addAttribute("listUsers", this.userService.getListUsers());

    return "users";
}

@RequestMapping("/userdata/{id}")
public String userData(@PathVariable("id") int id, Model model){
    model.addAttribute("user", this.userService.getUserById(id));

    return "userdata";
}
}
```

Стек трейс :

```
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.19.1:test (default-test) on project UserManger: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\Users\zosia\Desktop\JAVA\CRUD\PROJECT\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: There are test failures.

Please refer to C:\Users\zosia\Desktop\JAVA\CRUD\PROJECT\target\surefire-reports for the individual test results.
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefireHelper.reportExecution(SurefireHelper.java:91)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.SurefirePlugin.handleSummary(SurefirePlugin.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.executeAfterPreconditionsChecked(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:892)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.AbstractSurefireMojo.execute(AbstractSurefireMojo.java:755)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 20 more
```

Comment: Полный стек трейс укажите

Comment: @GenCloud  Добавила полный стек трейс

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Просмотрите директорию

```
C:\Users\zosia\Desktop\JAVA\CRUD\PROJECT\target\surefire-reports
```

для просмотра ошибки самого теста. Прописан данный параметр

```
<build>
  <testSourceDirectory>src/test/java</testSourceDirectory>
</build>
```

Comment: Извините, я просто ещё не очень хорошо разбираюсь в теме) Ошибка самого теста в текстовом файле или xml? Потому, что в текстовом только Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 4.502 sec <<< FAILURE! - in usermanager.AppTests
simple(usermanager.AppTests)  Time elapsed: 4.01 sec  <<< FAILURE!
java.lang.AssertionError: No ModelAndView found
 at usermanager.AppTests.simple(AppTests.java:35)